# How to get an integer from stdin? Fast. Can trade accuracy for performance

Tags: c, linux, embedded, atoi

I'm trying to come up with a fast and simple

> "Get a string from stdin and convert to an integer. If you can't, just pretend we got zero".

This is a Linux embedded system, CPU and memory are at a premium. Performance is important, accuracy not so much. This should be able to do multiple ingests per second. I will eventually turn it into a daemon and store latest 1024 values in an array.

Here's my take using `atoi`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[] ) {
  char *c = argv[1];
  unsigned int i = 1; /* on atoi() failure, i = 0 */

  if (i = atoi(c)) {
      puts ("atoi() success");
  }
  else {
      puts ("atoi() FAILED");
  }

  printf("argv[1] = %s\n", argv[1]);
  printf("      i = %d\n", i);
}
```

A few test runs / fuzzing:

```
# ./test_atoi 3
atoi() success
argv[1] = 3
      i = 3

# ./test_atoi 99999999999999999999
atoi() success
argv[1] = 99999999999999999999
      i = 2147483647

# ./test_atoi 3.14159
atoi() success
argv[1] = 3.14159
      i = 3

# ./test_atoi $(echo -ne "\u2605")
atoi() FAILED
argv[1] = ★
      i = 0
```

This fails:

```
# ./test_atoi $(echo -e "\0")
Segmentation fault
```

I'll add a check for NUL then:

```c
if (argv[1] == '\0') {
    i = 0;
}
```

Will this be enough? Have i just (badly) re-implemented `strtol`?
Should i just go ahead and use `strtol`? If yes, anything i should be checking for, that `strtol` isn't already?

What i really really care about is not dying because of bad input. I can happily live with getting occasional garbage from the conversion.

EDIT: `int i = 1` just because i want to see if atoi() makes it 0.

### Ghetto profiling with time

EDIT: i've dropped the print statements and wrapped reading from stdin into atoi/strtol in a for loop.

```
# time seq 0 999888 | ./test_atoi
real    0m5.245s
user    0m5.870s
sys     0m0.030s

# time seq 0 999888 | ./test_atoi
real    0m5.230s
user    0m5.960s
sys     0m0.050s

# time seq 0 999888 | ./test_atoi
real    0m5.395s
user    0m5.920s
sys     0m0.080s

# time seq 0 999888 | ./test_strtol    
real    0m5.332s
user    0m5.860s
sys     0m0.030s

# time seq 0 999888 | ./test_strtol
real    0m5.023s
user    0m5.790s
sys     0m0.060s

# time seq 0 999888 | ./test_strtol
real    0m5.286s
user    0m5.970s
sys     0m0.010s
```

#### Alright, this is insane. I should do something more productive with my time, and yours!

Comment: Well, how did the performance compare to strtol?

Comment: In what bizzaro world is the parsing of the integers the bottleneck of a program that reads "multiple" integers per second? Saying "it's embedded" is not an excuse to optimize blindly. If it can run Linux, it has more than enough horse power to parse a few integers. I second Oliver's question, and furthermore inquire how the resources it (either `strtol` or your custom code) takes compare to the total resources you have available.

Comment: `if (argv[1] == '\0')` isn't quite right. `argv[1]` is a `char*`, `'\0'` is a `char`.  You want to check `if (argv[1] == NULL)`. Better yet, just check `argc` (believe it or not, `argc==1` when the program crashes).

Comment: Have you done any profiling?  Your I/O is likely going to be your botlleneck, not your conversion code.  Start with `strtol`, measure your performance, tweak from there.

Comment: Profiling added. Nothing to do here i guess. Will pick strtol and move on.

Comment: Where does any of this implement *"Get a string from stdin and convert to an integer. If you can't, just pretend we got zero"*?  You just convert command line arguments. Process instantiation takes much longer than the string conversion... Also `atoi` never *fails*, it returns `0` if the string does not start with a number after optional spaces and sign, but invokes undefined behaviour if the number is too large.

Comment: Your naming convention is confusing: `char *c`.  Assignment as test is very bad style, it will bite you sooner or later: `if (i = atoi(c)) ...`.  You should work on your style before focussing on raw performance.

Comment: Valid remarks. Taken.

Comment: Your profiling is probably irrelevant if it is for the code shown; you have measured the time taken for the OS to load, run and exit the executable which itself includes output to stdout.  It does not measure the performance of `atoi()` alone; which I would expect to take a matter of microseconds for short strings on almost any target, ans sub-μs on any target capable of running Linux.  The real bottleneck will probably be getting data into stdin in the first instance.  If CPU and memory are truly at a premium Linux is also probably an inappropriate choice, and an RTOS might be in order.

Comment: My bad, profiling is taken without any print statements, just a for loop ingesting one integer per line from stdin into strol/atoi. But yes, now i understand i'm chasing the wrong wild-goose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is a Linux embedded system, CPU and memory are at a premium.

Yes. Err, no. If you're running a normal linux, your kernel will use `atoi` and the inverse in a few thousand places. Your single number parser will hardly make any impact, unless you're intending to call it several thousand times per second...

> Should i just go ahead and use strtol?

for the reasons above: yes.

> If yes, anything i should be checking for, that strtol isn't already?

you should check `strtol`'s return value. I really don't sympathesize with your "don't need precision" approach. something like this is either done right, or catastrophically wrong.

**EDIT** You said:

> don't need precision = i only care about values 0 - 100

This means a) you just need `atoi`, not `atol`/`strtol`; there, CPU cycles saved. Next do you actually need to convert strings that might look like `13.288` to integers, or can you assume that all strings are 1 to three characters long? In that case, and for raw performance, maybe

```
inline unsigned char char2digit(const char *c) {
    unsigned char v = *c - '0';
    return (v<1 || v>9)? 0 : v;
}
inline signed char characters2number(const char *string)
{
    size_t len = strnlen(string,4);
    if(len < 1 || len > 3)
        return -1;
    signed char val = 0;
    signed char power_of_ten = 1;
    for(unsigned char idx = 1; idx <= len; ++idx)
    {
        signed char val += power_of_ten * char2digit(string + len - idx)
        power_of_ten *= 10;
    }
    return val;
}
```

I mean, if you're on a toaster. Otherwise `atoi` has your back. You might still want to check `strnlen`.

Comment: `don't need precision` = i only care about values 0 - 100. If i'm getting anything else, from my point of view, it's garbage. You make a very valid point, i am running a regular linux kernel, and i'm probably worrying in the wrong place, i should probably focus on solid error handling.

Answer (score -1):

```
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
     int i = 0;

     if (argc > 1)
         sscanf (argv [1], "%d", &i);

     printf ("i = %d\n", i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i'm not sure how `sscanf` is better or different than `strtol` or `atoi`.

Comment: it's definitely not. Just adds (if compilers weren't so darn clever) unnecessary format string parsing.

Comment: missing `int` return type before `main`.  Interestingly, testing the return value of `sscanf` is not needed as `i` is set to `0` before the call and will not be changed if `argv[1]` does not start with a number.